# Setting order to categorical data while creating count plot ( ) results in erroneous plot

Tags: python, seaborn, categorical-data

I have a column in my dataframe for different age groups which has 174 rows of data. A sample is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL81D.png)

My code to print a countplot() of this column is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import os

sns.set(rc = {'figure.figsize':(15,8)})
sns.countplot(data = variable, x = 'Q2')
plt.title("Respondents as per age group")
```

The resulting output is:
[Count of respondents as per age-group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rkr3K.jpg)

As can be seen the order of the categories in the x axis is not right.

I used the following code the set the order:

```
age_order = ['15-19','20-29','30-39','40-49','50-59','60 and above']
sns.countplot(x = 'Q2', data = variable, order = age_order)
plt.title("Respondents as per age group")
```

But the result is:

[Count of respondents as per age-group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXg4i.png)

Which is obviously incorrect.

I have no idea why this is happening and how to rectify this.

Comment: It seems the string in your `age_order` and your dataframe aren't exactly the same. For example, the strings in the dataframe seem to have more spaces. The easiests is to do `print(variable['Q2'].unique())` and then use the result string to create `age_order`,

Comment: Thank you @JohanC that was indeed the issue.